# How to implement a custom sliding banner?

Tags: php, templates, custom-header

I need to make a custom slider with images (same images on all pages) in a template I am crafting for a client. Each of the slides could have a link to one of the pages. How and where should I store images, so the client will have no problem adding them or changing links?

Comment: Have you tried searching for a slider [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/)? You should show some kind of research effort when asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of slider pluglins in wordpress repository such http://wordpress.org/plugins/slide-show-pro/, just follow the install steps. then use the shortcodes like  `[slideshowpro cats=2,3]`  or the code to integrate into php  
 `php echo do_shortcode('[slideshowpro cats=2,3]');`  
insert the code in header.php to show the slider on every single page or post